# How do I tar a Spring web application with embedded jetty and all dependencies using maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a simple Spring web app with an embedded Jetty server that I would like to package into a tar with all dependencies so that I can use a wrapper to run it as a service on a Windows server. How would I go about doing this? If there's any code I need to post, please ask for it. Thanks!

Edit:For clarification, I'm only asking for how to tar everything together. I already know how to tie it into a wrapper. Thanks.

Edit2: For clarity on how my application works, below is my application context. I have a main() function that I want the service wrapper to call which will instantiate these beans.

```
    <bean id="myHandler" class="my.package.MyHandler"></bean>
<bean id="server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server" init-method="start"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg value="8080" />
    <property name="handler" ref="myHandler" />
</bean>
```

Comment: can you explain the target Windows Server a bit? does it have internet connection available? does it have maven installed? it has Java installed right? what do you mean exactly the jetty server? jetty-maven-plugin? you want to start the app on that server like `mvn jetty:run`, so the codes would be built and start jetty?

Comment: @Kent updated good sir

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Maven, maybe the best idea is to package just your app into a WAR file (with no embedded servers) using the "maven-war-plugin" (take a look: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).

You will obtain an standard deployment file (WAR) ready to run in any servlet container.

You also take a look to this maven plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/introduction.html

Comment: I think the OP wants an executable jar that will run its own server. This answer doesn't really help.

Comment: OP wants to skip the container part, just click or type xxx[enter], the webapp will be running there... :)

Comment: @bmorris591 Yes, I need it to run its own server. I want to be able to stop and start it in Windows services.

Comment: you're right, I started to write the answer just before his change, so I added the reference to maven-assembly-plugin